# How to fix some view in horizontal scroll View when user reached on start position?

Tags: android, horizontal-scrolling

I want to fix first and Third view in horizontal scroll view.I don't want to scroll fixed view.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to understand; you're not very clear on what you're asking, and you're not showing what you've tried. I suppose is something like this. I think easiest way is to reduce your scroll view and fix it above and below the other fixed views based on its IDs; you can put all this inside a RelativeLayout, that could perform better.

This code should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.something.MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/view02"
    android:layout_below="@id/view01"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" >
</HorizontalScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/view02"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout> </RelativeLaytout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As you have not mentioned enough details as per my understanding of your question.

Below code will help you to fix first and third view fixed and second will be scrollable.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

   <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/view01"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/view02"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.34"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
               <HorizontalScrollView
                      android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
               </HorizontalScrollView>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/view03"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="0.33"
          android:orientation="horizontal" >
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```